# How do I disable the ${appName}.elasticbeanstalk.com URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare, amazon-route53

Here's my scenario:

1. I have an Amazon EB application
2. I use a third party DNS/cache/attack-protection service (Cloudflare) instead of Route 53

**Problem**:
Search engines are (also) crawling and indexing my ${appName}.elasticbeanstalk.com URL

**Q**: How do I disable the ${appName}.elasticbeanstalk.com URL for good to only use my chosen (.com) name?

Comment: Does your cloudflare map to  YOURAPPNAME.elasticbeanstalk.com?  or does it map to a load balancer?

Comment: Currently I have a CNAME record pointing to ${appName}.elasticbeanstalk.com.

I understand that if I could get rid of this .elasticbeanstalk.com URL I would then need have an A record pointing to the load balancer IP. Which raises another question: can I assign an AWS Public IP to an EBS environment?

Comment: Hi there. Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: Best thing I could find was to add a some redirect entries to my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer with the best thing I've found so far, just to make sure I can help other people.

Assuming there is no way to completely disable the elasticbeanstalk URL, best thing I found was to add an entry to .htaccess file redirecting.

```
# Redirect elastic beanstalk addresses to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} elasticbeanstalk\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can do something better to consider your testing environments as well.

Comment: Where did you put this .htaccess? Manually or with some .ebextension ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you set a rule on your server to instruct search engines not to crawl that particular url (robots.txt, etc.)?

Comment: **As far as my knowledge goes**, "no index" tags are placed in the html code. If I place them there, it will also avoid "mywebsite.com" to be crawled.